# The extent of customization for communities

Tags: customer-community

I need to build a site for customer interaction, but the wire frames for the case details page are very different from the case detail pages on all of the templates. I also need a 6 step user questionnaire to collect data from the customer. Is it possible to build customized pages for the questions and case detail page without having to build lightning components?

Is a site better choice for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Both, site and communities allow you to use visualforce pages, meaning, you can do pretty much everything you want in them. I have seen highly customized sites and communities so is really up to you. Considering, all new features go to communities you might be better by implementing choosing that option.

Comment: Could yo please elaborate what the new features are? The issue I am having with communities is that i am forced to use templates and I don't want to use any of the available templates. I understand I can build custom visual pages for everything in communities, but I am thinking if I am not going to use their template for any page I am building, what would be the benefit of using communities?